# reading xml with Linq

Tags: xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I cannot figure out how to get the all the ItemDetail nodes in the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AssessmentMetadata xmlns="http://tempuri.org/AssessmentMetadata.xsd">
   <ItemDetails>
    <ItemName>I1200</ItemName>
    <ISC_Inactive_Codes>NS,NSD,NO,NOD,ND,NT,SP,SS,SSD,SO,SOD,SD,ST,XX</ISC_Inactive_Codes>
    <ISC_StateOptional_Codes>NQ,NP</ISC_StateOptional_Codes>
  </ItemDetails>
  <ItemDetails>
    <ItemName>I1300</ItemName>
    <ISC_Inactive_Codes>NS,NSD,NO,NOD,ND,NT,SP,SS,SSD,SO,SOD,SD,ST,XX</ISC_Inactive_Codes>
    <ISC_StateOptional_Codes>NQ,NP</ISC_StateOptional_Codes>
  </ItemDetails>
  <ItemDetails>
    <ItemName>I1400</ItemName>
    <ISC_Active_Codes>NC</ISC_Active_Codes>
    <ISC_Inactive_Codes>NS,NSD,NO,NOD,ND,NT,SP,SS,SSD,SO,SOD,SD,ST,XX</ISC_Inactive_Codes>
    <ISC_StateOptional_Codes>NQ,NP</ISC_StateOptional_Codes>
  </ItemDetails>
</AssessmentMetadata>
```

I have tried a number of things, I am thinking it might be a namespace issue, so this is my last try:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(asmtMetadata.Filepath);
var assessmentMetadata = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("/AssessmentMetadata");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the default namespace and use it when querying:

```
var ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var query = xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "ItemDetails");
```

You'll need to prefix it for any element. For example, the following query retrieves all `ItemName` values:

```
var itemNames = xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "ItemDetails")
                    .Elements(ns + "ItemName")
                    .Select(n => n.Value);
```